# Parse DateTime from ShortFormat C#

Tags: c#

I am trying convert string which is in shortdate format of Year-Month to a DateTime
for eg  "2018-04" is converted to DateTime 2018-04-1 00:00:00

I do this with following syntax

```
DateTime newDate=DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM",oldString,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

above scenario works. but there is one glitch

I thought this syntax can also handle format like 2018-4 (note the missing trailing zero in month)

But it does not and throws exception, invalid datetime format.

Is there another solution to this, before I try a hacky workaround?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are expecting to receive dates in both formats? Ie '2016-04' and '2016-4'. Where is this data coming from? Can you enforce the format you get it in?

Comment: Of course `DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM",oldString` is totally wrong, should be  `DateTime.ParseExact(oldString, "yyyy-MM"` So I'm surprised that you say *this works*?

Answer (score 4):

No need to do workarounds `yyyy-M` will parse single and double digit month numbers just fine:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(oldString, "yyyy-M", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

*Note that I have swapped the first two arguments since they were in the wrong order*